# how can I trigger a function after a defined time of inserting

Tags: mysql

I have a table containing products. If I insert a row, I want this row to get updated after a time delay of 30 minutes.

**Explanation**

- I have a table of products.
- When a client buys a product, a row gets inserted in table order.

**The Problem**

- If the status of that row did not change from `status_id = 1` to `status_id = 2` within 30 minutes, I want to update it to `status_id = 6`.

I'm using MySQL with the PHP framework Laravel.

How can I do that?

Comment: Which DBMS? sql server is not the same thing as mysql. And what do you mean you want to update a row 30 minutes after it is inserted? That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I think, only with mysql it does not work, but with a language like php, etc.

Comment: That is probably the wrong design for what you want to do.  It is possible, using a message queuing architecture of some sort, but there are probably simpler methods to accomplish what you need.

Comment: Could be done with an [event](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-event.html)

Comment: @PaulSpiegel How can I do that? an event every minute??

Comment: Yes. Though i don't say it's a good idea. But it's possible. In the event you would have a statement like `update \`order\` set status_id = 6 where status_id = 1 and created_at < now() - interval 30 minute`